Cohomology for quantum groups
I'm interested in quantum groups for two perspectives:

Compact quantum groups in the sense of Woronowicz.
Deformation of the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra in the sense of Drinfeld & Jimbo.

I'm intetsed in knowing about what cohomology theories are out there for quantum groups from these perspectives. I would appreciate pointers to some references.
Edit: To elaborate on the question: is there a cohomology theory associated with groups such as $SO_q(n), SU_q(n)$ - essentially quantum analogs of classical compact Lie groups - in which the second cohomology group classifies projective representations? The problem I am working on hints me to investigate this question. So I’m naturally interested in the analog of continuous/Borel/Eilenberg-Moore (I’ve heard all these phrases being used) cohomology developed for compact topological (Lie) groups.
Borel cohomology: See this paper

You can have a look at the book "Compact quantum groups and their representation categories" by Neshveyev and Tuset, chapter 3.

I did. They develop a cohomology theory for discrete quantum groups. I'm interested in compact quantum groups, and I couldn't really find anything. I wonder, though, if an appropriate generalization of Pontryagin duality can allow us to pass between these two cases.

I am not really an expert on cohomology, but regarding CQGs, I think that if somebody studies their homological properties, it is usually the cohomology of the associated Hopf algebra, which as you said should rather be interpreted as the cohomology of the dual discrete (quantum) group. Regarding this problem, I would also recommend the survey by Bichon https://lmbp.uca.fr/~bichon/Seoul.pdf and a recent article https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.07767, where you can check the intro and references therein. You seem not to be really interested in that, but I am not aware of anything else.

@Daniel Thanks for the references. My problem, motivated from the physics literature, is restricted to the case of compact quantum groups - most notably of the form $SU_q(n)$ and $SO_q(n)$. Essentially compact quantum groups obtained as deformations of the classical compact Lie grapups. Do you know if Tannaka-Krein duality can be exploited to develop a cohomology theory - in low dimensions at the very least - for these compact quantum groups.

The (non-$C^\ast$-completed) algebras of matrix coefficients of $q$-deformed compact Lie groups, e.g., $\mathcal{O}(SU_q(n))$, admit non-trivial (twisted) Hochschild and cyclic homology as associative algebras that has been studied in the literature. For example, in the case of quantum $SU(2)$, non-twisted Hochschild and cyclic homology was computed by Masuda-Nakagami-Watanabe while twisted Hochschild and cyclic homology was computed by Hadfield-Krähmer.

Once you equip such quantum groups with covariant or bicovariant differential calculi (e.g., the left-covariant $3$-dimensional calculus on quantum $SU(2)$ of Woronowicz), you can also compute the usual cohomology of the differential calculi qua DGA and get a naive generalization of de Rham cohomology. There's finally been enough work on Hodge decomposition and relevant spectral sequences in the noncommutative setting for such naive NC de Rham cohomology to have finally become realistically computable.

There is also the unfinished programme of Kustermans-Murphy-Tuset to relate such naive NC de Rham cohomology to twisted cyclic homology, and I hope that someone someday will pick up the thread. The NC differential geometry of quantum homogeneous spaces (e.g., the NC Kähler geometry programme of Ó Buachalla) is far better understood than that of quantum groups.
